# ¿Cuándo es correcto usar el plural de "ninguno"?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, plurales, número-gramatical

Me encontré con lo siguiente, tomado de *17 ecuaciones que cambiaron el mundo* de Ian Stewart:

[image: recorte "ningunas bases físicas"]

> (...) Su fórmula, obtenida a principios de 1900, inicialmente no tenía **ningunas** bases físicas. Era tan solo una fórmula que funcionaba. (...)

y de inmediato sentí que "ningunas bases físicas" es poco lógico y suena mal. El libro fue traducido desde el inglés.

Realmente no sabría cómo explicarlo de buenas a primeras, pero me parece que debería decir que no tenía "ninguna base física", en singular.

¿Es, o podría ser, correcto decir en algún contexto que *hay ningunos de algo*? O, planteado de otra forma, ¿puede "ningunas bases físicas" significar algo comprensible en español?

Comment: no creo... la nada es un concepto unico al igual que ninguno, deberia ser unicamente: unos, uno o ninguno.

Comment: Me suena bien. Hay concordancia entre _ningunas_ y _bases_. No seria lógico decir _ninguna bases_ . Suena mal porque es redundante con **no tenia** Se podría simplificar a **no tenía bases ...** o cambiar a **no tenia inicialmente ningunas bases**

Comment: no seria lo correcto decir "ninguna base fisica"  ? 
"su formula no tenia ningunas bases fisicas" me suena fatal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La frase *ningunas bases físicas* suena incorrecta (de hecho salta a la vista como incorrecta; en inglés diría que es hasta *cringeworthy*). Aunque no sea estrictamente antigramatical, *ningunos/ningunas* no se utiliza actualmente así (explicación más abajo). A mí me da la fuerte impresión de que un mal traductor tradujo literalmente del inglés [verbno en negativo + *any* + sustantivo en plural] o bien [*no* + sustantivo en plural].

La explicación, tomada del [foro](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=42326#169871) del Centro Virtual Cervantes (que refiere a [NGLE 19.4f-g](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wnPDwYogPECDUpdj)):

> Los plurales *ningunos/ningunas* se usan cuando constituyen la
>   contrapartida del artículo indeterminado con valor enfático. Así, a la
>   oración afirmativa *«Tus amigos son unos tontos»* corresponde la
>   negativa *«Tus amigos no son ningunos tontos»*, en alternancia con la
>   invariable *«... no son unos tontos»*.
>
> También se aceptan las formas *ningunos/ningunas* con sustantivos que
>   contienen plurales inherentes (*pluralia tántum*). El sustantivo más
>   frecuente en esta pauta es *ganas*, aunque no el único: *«Me parecía
>   que Nehru no tenía ningunas ganas de decirme nada»* (Arrau, Norte).
>
> Se extiende a veces el plural *ningunos/ningunas* a los sustantivos
>   que designan cosas que se presentan normalmente en pares, como en
>   *«Quería comprar botas, pero no encontró ningunas a su medida»*.
>   La misma pauta aparece en ocasiones en los plurales estilísticos: *«Los
>   primeros tenían esperanzas de mandar después de la separación y los
>   últimos ningunas o muy pocas»* (Marías, España).

La NGLE (19.4e) aclara que *ningunos/ningunas* sí se usaba en el español medieval y clásico y con menor frecuencia en épocas posteriores.

Comment: It might well be a bad translation from English as you say but I think the correct English would have been singular anyway. It did not have any physical basis.

Comment: Sí, no dudo que fuera una mala traducción. Pero en el original sí se podría haber empleado el plural: "it had no physical bases."

Comment: @MichaelWolf - No estoy de acuerdo con "it had no physical bases" en este caso.  Véase mi respuesta donde hablo precisamente de esto.

Answer (score 2):

I like Pablo's answer but I want to look at this from a slightly different point of view.

Let's look at the original text, in English (from *In Pursuit of the Unknown* by Ian Stewart):

> He [Planck] used experimental observations of how energy depended on frequency, and fitted a mathematical formula to the data.  **His formula, derived early in 1900, did not initially have any physical basis.**

The translator appears to have mistaken *basis* for *bases*, which is the plural of *basis*.  The negative statement goes with the singular noun.  An affirmative statement, on the other hand, can use either the singular and plural, as the situation calls for.

An [example](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198249801.001.0001/acprof-9780198249801-chapter-4) of the plural, correctly used (taken from *Physicalism: The Philosophical Foundations*, by Jeffrey Poland):

> This chapter is devoted to the identification of the physical bases of the physicalist system. | *Este capítulo trata sobre la identificación de las bases físicas del sistema fisicalista.* [my own translation]

Let's get back to Stewart's sentence.  What Stewart is saying is that when Planck wrote down a formula to model his "experimental observations of how energy depends on frequency," his formula was purely empirical.  He was just fitting the data -- as opposed to starting from first principles.  In other words, there was no physical basis for the formula he wrote down; he wasn't describing reality as he saw it.  This is like when an art historian compares a an abstract painting, A, with a still life, B, by saying that the painting A wasn't based on a concrete physical object.  Thus, we are talking about a singular entity.  We're saying that the formula, and the painting, are *not* based on that singular entity.

When *ningún/ninguno/ninguna* modifies a singular noun, it has to be singular, by the principle of number agreement.